# Como adicionar uma progressbar a minha aplicação?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma *Activity* que chama um método no `oncreate` que criei que se chama `criarlista()`. Este método cria uma `ListView` carregando de um XML, e esse processo demora em torno de uns 3,4 segundos pois esta carregando de um XML.

Como faço para durante esse tempo, rodar uma barra de progresso simples?

Alguém poderia postar um exemplo, se baseando no meu modelo?

Comment: Já viste: [Adicionar progressbar na minha webview](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37654/223) ?

Comment: Isso ai foi na webview, agora quero antes da chamada de um listview, nao consegui implementar, quero fazer com thread

Comment: Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: É isto que queres? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7496195/1817673

Comment: @WarLock Considere postar uma resposta se conseguiu, e como conseguiu resolver seu problema. Até porque dois comentários lhe propuseram uma ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

tenho um modelo em um webview

MainAcitivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.clearHistory();

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mundodamulher.com.br/");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (findViewById(R.id.splach_screen).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // show webview
            findViewById(R.id.main_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // hide splash screen
            findViewById(R.id.splach_screen).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/webViewProgress"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:indeterminateTint="#e20400"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

sei que a mudança de cor da barra funciona acima de api 21, ainda to procurando para api's inferiores